# Images in Toast or Snackbar

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am building an application that targets Windows, Mac, IOS and Android.
I am using .NET Maui.
Is it possible to display an image or images in a **toast** or **snackbar** using the .Net Maui Community Toolkit? If so, can you provide an example please? if not, is there another way to achieve this.
I have looked at all the documentation I can find but have not been able to find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible. A SnackBar/Toas control is designed to show a simple (text) message and at most 1 action that is associated with it. If you want to show images and such you will either have to implement something custom or maybe look at the [Popup implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) in the Community Toolkit.

Comment: I apprecciate this answer but when my toast noticiation shows there is a .net icon in it. Can I remove that somehow?